# How to remove duplicate values generated randomly from list in python

Tags: python, list, random

I am having a list of input points as:

```
input_points = [{'name': 'a', 'value': (0.0, 1.0)}, {'name': 'b', 'value': (2.0, 1.0)},
                {'name': 'c', 'value': (3.0, 1.0)}, {'name': 'd', 'value': (0.0, 3.0)},
                {'name': 'e', 'value': (1.0, 2.0)}, {'name': 'f', 'value': (1.5, 1.5)},
                {'name': 'g', 'value': (1.0, 1.0)}, {'name': 'h', 'value': (1.5, 2.0)}]
```

I have to generate two random points iteratively. I am using random.sample() as:

```
for x in range(100):
    point1 = random.sample(input_points, 2)
    print(point1)
```

But it gives me a combination of duplicate points that's why I am not getting the combination of all the points from the list in 100 iterations all the time. But I have to traverse all the points in 100 iterations only. Is there any way I can remove the duplicates do that I get the combination of all the points in 100 iterations.

Thanks

Comment: There aren't 100 unique 2-point combinations of for a list of 8 points. Also using `random` is not the best way to find all possible combinations. Is this a school assessment? What are the restrictions?

Comment: There will be 28 unique combinations for 8 points and I have a restriction to select all the unique combination of 2 points from 8 points in 100 iterations.

Comment: Do you have to use `random` though? This can trivially be accomplished using two nested `for` loops in exactly 28 iterations.

Comment: There is a computational time restriction too actually I have to calculate the best line fit of those points by implementing ransac algorithm. I am not restricted to use random. Can you tell me how to implement this using nested loops

Comment: Well, ransac algorithm depends on random samples, so I'm not sure the iterative method will help you in accomplishing that, but I'll post an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all iterations, iteratively using nested loops:

```
pairs = []
for i, point1 in enumerate(input_points):
    for point2 in input_points[i+1:]:
        pairs.append([point1, point2])
```

Ransac algorithm, however, depends on random samples and how well they fit into a model.

Answer (score 0):

We could:

1) create all pairs of combinations of points.

2) take random sampling of these pairs.

```
import random
from itertools import combinations

input_points = [{'name': 'a', 'value': (0.0, 1.0)}, {'name': 'b', 'value': (2.0, 1.0)},
                {'name': 'c', 'value': (3.0, 1.0)}, {'name': 'd', 'value': (0.0, 3.0)},
                {'name': 'e', 'value': (1.0, 2.0)}, {'name': 'f', 'value': (1.5, 1.5)},
                {'name': 'g', 'value': (1.0, 1.0)}, {'name': 'h', 'value': (1.5, 2.0)}]

all_pairs = list(combinations(input_points, 2))

y = random.sample(all_pairs, 10) # random sample of pairs 
                                 # (in this case 10 pairs)
                                 # max we could get is 28
```